# CRA window.location.reload(true) not updating PWA

Tags: javascript, reactjs, service-worker, create-react-app

I'm using Create-react-app and I registered the serviceWorker that comes with.

```
import * as serviceWorker from "./serviceWorker"

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
  super(props)
  serviceWorker.register({
    onUpdate: this.handleServiceWorkerUpdate
  })
 }
}
```

the `handleServiceWorkerUpdate()` function prompts the user if he/she wants to update the PWA/Website and if yes I run `window.location.reload(true)`

This does however not give the user the latest version of the PWA. The user needs to ctr + shift + reload the website or if an installed PWA they need to hard close the app and reopen it to get the latest version.

How can a I give the user the latest version without telling them no manually hard refresh/reload the app?

The CRA serviceWorker I have not changed anything in this file.
https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/src/serviceWorker.js#L79